# I want a date select box with blank values selected by default

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I used the following `date_select` helpers but none of them shows a date select box with blank values selected by default. With all the following code, I get the select box but with the current date selected. I'm on Rails 2.3.2

```
<%= f.date_select :featured_at, :default => {:day => nil, :month => nil, :year => nil} %>
<%#= date_select("post", "featured_at", :prompt => { :day => 'Select day', :month => 'Select month', :year => 'Select year' }) %>
<%#= date_select("post", "featured_at", :default => { :day => nil }) %>
<%#= f.date_select :featured_at, :include_blank => true, :order => [:day, :month, :year] %>
```

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Far easier to do this:

```
<%= f.date_select :featured_at, {:include_blank => true, :default => nil} %>
```

Answer (score 9):

```
 <%= f.label :expired %><br />
    <%= f.datetime_select :expired,:prompt => { :day => 'Select day', :month => 'Select month', :year => 'Select year' }  %>
```

works for me

Answer (score 0):

Additionally, `prompt: true` works as well:

```
<%= f.date_select :deadline, {order: [:day, :month, :year], prompt: true} %>
```

Better to show `day, month, year` rather than blank probably in most cases.