# Placeholder in a select_date rails 3

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, forms, placeholder

I can normally put a placeholder within a form using something like

```
:placeholder => "something" or {:placehoder => "something"}
```

I am a little stumped on how to put a place-holder for the month and year within a select_date. I am using this

```
<%= select_date(date = Date.current, :order => [:month, :year]) %>
```

I would like a place-holder in the month and the year

Anyone know how to achieve this please

Thanks

Answer (score 6):

Placeholder for select? Haven't heard of anything like this. Maybe you want:

```
 <%=  select_date(date = Date.current, :order => [:month, :year], :prompt => { :month => 'Select month', :year => 'Select year' }  %>
```

[Here is the answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1423974/877581) that inspired me, so you might want to credit philipth. I just adjusted it to your case. You can check [documentation](http://api.rubyonrails.org/classes/ActionView/Helpers/DateHelper.html) if you need anything more. You can find such example there:

```
# Generates a date select with custom prompts.
date_select("article", "written_on", :prompt => { :day => 'Select day', :month => 'Select month', :year => 'Select year' })
```

Comment: many thanks for your answer, i can see how that works.. just tried it, the prompt is now within the dropdown but not the default value? any ideas?

Comment: I believe you can just delete `date = Date.current` from select_date, because most likely you are setting the default value

Comment: so :default => :prompt? so select the prompt as the default...is that possible? hmmm doesnt work

Comment: how about `:default => nil` ?

Comment: hmm I am running out of ideas.. the last thing that comes to my mind is `:default => { :month => nil }` and `:default => { :month => '' }` where '' is value for option with prompt [ I guess it is empty, but please ensure ]

Comment: i appreciate your assistance, so this doesnt work, <%= select_date(date = Date.current, :order => [:month, :year], :prompt => {:month => 'Select month', :year => 'Select Year'}, :default => {:month => nil, :year => nil})  anything look amiss?

Comment: I would just experiment with removing `date = Date.current`, changing `nil` to `''` etc...

Answer (score 0):

You should use `prompt: true` to make use of I18n translations

```rb
date_select :user, :date_of_birth, prompt: true
```

Translations keys are

```yaml
fr:
  datetime:
    prompts:
      day: Jour
      hour: Heure
      minute: Minute
      month: Mois
      second: Seconde
      year: Année
```